# How does mvn --encrypt-master-password <password> work?

Tags: maven, password-protection, password-encryption, password-generator

I would like to know the algorithm or technique used by this command (mvn --encrypt-master-password ). Each time I run it produces a different output. I'm assuming that it takes system time as a seed parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The encryption mechanism is not in the maven codebase per se. It is located on a library called `plexus-cipher`. It is always on the maven distribution. Mine is on `lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar` being `3.0.5` the maven version.

The actual cipher is `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. The key for the cipher and IV for the block chaining are derived iterating `SHA-256`-ing over the provided password (encoded as UTF-8) concatenated with a JVM-configuration-specific (usually `SHA1PRNG`) 64-bit random salt once or twice.

No big surprises here. It seems to be on the same format every other soul is using nowadays.

The gory details can be found reading the source on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-cipher)

Comment: So the 64-bit random salt provides the uniqueness each time, but the salt needs a seed as well, is it the system time or something else?

Comment: Depends on the random PRNG implementation it finds first. For instance, on linux, `NativePRNG` initializes itself reading its seed from `/dev/random`, which was cause for performance kerfuffle. I can't tell which system resources the fallback `SHA1PRNG` uses.