# How can two executions of mvn --encrypt-master-password or --encrypt-password get two differents results with same word?

Tags: maven, maven-3, password-encryption

Can two executions of mvn --encrypt-master-password or --encrypt-password get two differents results with same word?

```
mvn -encrypt-master-password
Master password: hi
{5je8mfa6JScHqquB9OgSQxQcS9yau+MKPES4VSVmnOw=} --first execution
{F+r2oNtSUi0HNBTvoREnyvEh6admHZGDwSwB0e2/U2Q=} --second execution
...
```

Same it happens with mvn --encrypt-password
Does it have any sense?

Comment: Yes of course. If it would give you every time the same result it could be "easily" revered and your security would be gone.

Comment: Please refer to the detailed answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769636/how-does-maven-3-password-encryption-work